# Adding event listener to a point

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, code-generation

([see problem in action](http://jsdo.it/phenix.pink/k3Bs/fullscreen))  generally my problem is - I can add elements with innerHTML, I can style them, but I can not `addEventListeners` on to them. Has any one seen such problem? ([see how it worked before I added html generation](http://jsdo.it/phenix.pink/3j2w))

So I have such simple JavaScript:

```
function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

/* ------------------------------------------------ */
var POINTS = $('points');
var W = 800, W1_2 = W / 2;
var H = 410, H1_2 = H / 2;
var FPS = 20, FRAMES = 0;
var str ="";
var CV = $('canvas');
var CX = CV.getContext('2d');
CV.width = W;
CV.height = H;

function reCoord(){
 // coort = $('coor');
 // coort.innerHTML = str;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------ */
var id = 0;
var Draggable = function(PointParams, x, y, callbacks) {
   var elementIdSring;
  var t = this;
       
  switch (PointParams) {
   case 'point':
      POINTS.innerHTML += '<div id="p' + id + '" class="point"></div>';   
     elementIdSring = 'p'+String(id);
        break;
   case 'cp1':
      POINTS.innerHTML += '<div id="p' + id + '" class="point cp1"></div>';
      elementIdSring = 'p'+String(id);
        break;
         case 'cp2':
      POINTS.innerHTML += '<div id="p' + id + '" class="point cp2"></div>';    
      elementIdSring = 'p'+String(id);
        break;     
                case 'limiter':
      POINTS.innerHTML += '<div id="l' + id + '" class="point limiter"></div>';    
      elementIdSring = 'l'+String(id);
        break;   
  }
 id++;
    coort = $('coor');
  coort.innerHTML += elementIdSring + ' ';
 var  e = $(elementIdSring);
  t.element = e;
  
  
  t.callbacks = {
    begin: function() {},
    end: function() {},
    drag: function() {}
  };
  if (callbacks != null) for (var v in callbacks) {
    switch (v) {
    case 'begin':
    case 'end':
    case 'drag':
      if (callbacks[v] instanceof Function)
        t.callbacks[v] = callbacks[v];
      break;
    }
  }
  t.move(x, y);
         var  e = $(elementIdSring);
  e.addEventListener('mousedown', function(ev) {
    if (ev.which == 1) {
      Draggable.Target = [t,
                          t.x - ev.clientX,
                          t.y - ev.clientY];
      t.callbacks.begin();
      ev.preventDefault();
      ev.stopPropagation();

    }
  }, false);
};

Draggable.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
reCoord();
  var s = this.element.style;
  s.left = (this.x = x) + 'px';
  s.top = (this.y = y) + 'px';   

};

Draggable.tracking = function(ev) {
    var t = Draggable.Target;
    str = 'X : ' +ev.clientX + ', ' + 'Y :' + ev.clientY ;
  if (t) {
    t[0].move(ev.clientX + t[1], ev.clientY + t[2]);
    t[0].callbacks.drag(); 

  }

};

Draggable.finish = function(ev) {
  var t = Draggable.Target;
  if (t) {
    t[0].move(ev.clientX + t[1], ev.clientY + t[2]);
    t[0].callbacks.end(); 
    coort = $('coor');
  coort.innerHTML = " ";
    Draggable.Target = null;
    
  }
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove',
                        Draggable.tracking, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup',
                        Draggable.finish, false);

/* ------------------------------------------------ */



var linePoints = [
          new Draggable('point', 50, 175),
          new Draggable('cp1', 175,  225),
          new Draggable('cp2', 175, 120),
          new Draggable('point', 350, 120),
          
          new Draggable('point', 370, 175),
          new Draggable('cp1', 475,  225),
          new Draggable('cp2', 475, 175),
          new Draggable('point', 650, 165),
  
          new Draggable('point', 50, 275) ,
          new Draggable('cp1', 175, 225),
          new Draggable('cp2', 175, 325),
          new Draggable('point', 350, 325),
  

          new Draggable('point', 370, 275) ,
          new Draggable('cp1', 475, 225),
          new Draggable('cp2', 475, 275),
          new Draggable('point', 650, 285)
         ];




var Limits = [
          new Draggable('limiter', 50, 150),
          new Draggable('limiter', 650, 150),
          new Draggable('limiter', 50, 300) ,
          new Draggable('limiter', 650, 300)
 
         ];

/* ------------------------------------------------ */
window.addEventListener('mousemove',
                        Draggable.tracking, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup',
                        Draggable.finish, false);
var MODE = 1;

function line(p0, p1, p2, p3, t) {
  return [(1 - t) * p0.x + t * p3.x,
          (1 - t) * p0.y + t * p3.y];
}

function quadratic(p0, p1, p2, p3, t) {
  var s = 1 - t;
  return [s*s*p0.x + 2*s*t*p1.x + t*t*p3.x,
          s*s*p0.y + 2*s*t*p1.y + t*t*p3.y];
}

function bezier(p0, p1, p2, p3, t) {
  var s = 1 - t;
  return [s*s*s*p0.x + 3*s*s*t*p1.x +
          3*s*t*t*p2.x + t*t*t*p3.x,
          s*s*s*p0.y + 3*s*s*t*p1.y +
          3*s*t*t*p2.y + t*t*t*p3.y];
}

function catmull(p0, p1, p2, p3, t) {
  var v = [(p2.x - p0.x)/2, (p2.y - p0.y)/2];
  var w = [(p3.x - p1.x)/2, (p3.y - p1.y)/2];
  return [(2*p1.x-2*p2.x+v[0]+w[0])*t*t*t +
          (-3*p1.x+3*p2.x-2*v[0]-w[0])*t*t +
          v[0]*t + p1.x,
          (2*p1.y-2*p2.y+v[1]+w[1])*t*t*t +
          (-3*p1.y+3*p2.y-2*v[1]-w[1])*t*t +
          v[1]*t + p1.y];
}

/* ------------------------------------------------ */
var TYPE = $('type');


TYPE.addEventListener('change', redraw, false);

function drawArrow(type, t, P0, P1, P2, P3) {
  var c, c0, c1;
  c0 = window[type](P0, P1, P2, P3, t - 0.1);
  c  = window[type](P0, P1, P2, P3, t);
  c1 = window[type](P0, P1, P2, P3, t + 0.1);
  CX.save();
  CX.translate(c[0], c[1]);
  CX.rotate(Math.atan2(c1[1] - c0[1], c1[0] - c0[0]));
  CX.beginPath();
  CX.moveTo(0, 0);
  CX.lineTo(-10, 10);
  CX.lineTo(-10, -10);
  CX.closePath();
  CX.stroke();
  CX.restore();
}

function locLiner(P0start,P3end, color){
 CX.strokeStyle = color;
    CX.beginPath();
  CX.moveTo(P0start.x, P0start.y);
    CX.lineTo(P3end.x, P3end.y);
   CX.stroke();
}

function locBesier(P0start, cp1, cp2, P3end){
    CX.strokeStyle = '#000';
    CX.beginPath();
    CX.moveTo(P0start.x, P0start.y);
    CX.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y,
                     cp2.x, cp2.y,
                     P3end.x, P3end.y);
    CX.stroke();
    CX.strokeStyle = '#ccc';
    CX.beginPath();
    CX.moveTo(P0start.x, P0start.y);
    CX.lineTo(cp1.x, cp1.y);
    CX.lineTo(cp2.x, cp2.y);
    CX.lineTo(P3end.x, P3end.y);
    CX.stroke(); 
     
}

function locQuadratic(P0start, cp1, P3end){
 CX.strokeStyle = '#000';  
   CX.beginPath();
  CX.moveTo(P0start.x, P0start.y);
    CX.quadraticCurveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y,
                        P3end.x, P3end.y);
    CX.stroke();

    CX.strokeStyle = '#ccc';
    CX.beginPath();
    CX.moveTo(P0start.x, P0start.y);
    CX.lineTo(cp1.x, cp1.y);
    CX.lineTo(P3end.x, P3end.y);
    CX.stroke();
  
}

function redraw() {
  var type = TYPE.value, i, c, c0, c1, t, d;
  CX.setTransform(1,0, 0,1, 0,0);
  CX.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

  CX.setTransform(1,0, 0,1, -10,-10);
   
   for(i =0; i<Limits.length; i=i+2){locLiner(Limits [i], Limits[i+1], '#FF0000');} 

  CX.strokeStyle = '#000';
  CX.beginPath();

  switch (POINTS.className = type) {
  case 'line':
      for(i =0; i<linePoints.length; i=i+4){locLiner(linePoints[i], linePoints[i+3], '#000');}

    break;
  case 'quadratic':
for(i =0; i<linePoints.length; i=i+4){locQuadratic(linePoints[i], linePoints[i+1], linePoints[i+3]);}
      
      
    break;
  case 'bezier':
      for(i =0; i<linePoints.length; i=i+4){locBesier(linePoints[i], linePoints[i+1], linePoints[i+2], linePoints[i+3]);}
  
    break;

  default:
    return;
  }
 for(i =3; i<linePoints.length; i=i+16){locLiner(linePoints[i], linePoints[i+1]); CX.beginPath();
                                         CX.strokeStyle = '#000000'; 
            CX.fillStyle   = '#38A1DB';                          
   CX.moveTo(linePoints[i].x,linePoints[i].y);
                                         
    CX.bezierCurveTo(linePoints[i].x , (linePoints[i].y +( linePoints[i+1].y - linePoints[i].y)/2), linePoints[i+1].x, (linePoints[i].y +( linePoints[i+1].y - linePoints[i].y)/2), linePoints[i+1].x,linePoints[i+1].y);
      CX.bezierCurveTo(linePoints[i+1].x , (linePoints[i+1].y +( linePoints[i+8+1].y - linePoints[i+1].y)/2), linePoints[i+8+1].x, (linePoints[i+1].y +( linePoints[i+8+1].y - linePoints[i+1].y)/2), linePoints[i+8+1].x,linePoints[i+8+1].y);
    CX.bezierCurveTo(linePoints[i+8+1].x , (linePoints[i+8+1].y +( linePoints[i+8].y - linePoints[i+8+1].y)/2), linePoints[i+8].x, (linePoints[i+8+1].y +( linePoints[i+8].y - linePoints[i+8+1].y)/2), linePoints[i+8].x,linePoints[i+8].y);
           CX.bezierCurveTo(linePoints[i+8].x , (linePoints[i+8].y +( linePoints[i].y - linePoints[i+8].y)/2), linePoints[i].x, (linePoints[i+8].y +( linePoints[i].y - linePoints[i+8].y)/2), linePoints[i].x,linePoints[i].y);                                
   CX.fill(); 
    }

  CX.strokeStyle = '#39B7CD';

   for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
      for(j =0; j<linePoints.length; j=j+4){   drawArrow(type, (i + FRAMES % 10) / 100, linePoints[j], linePoints[j+1], linePoints[j+2], linePoints[j+3]);}
  }
  
  ++FRAMES;

}

setInterval(redraw, 1500 / FPS);
```

and some html:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<div id="points"></div>
<p id="coor"></p>
<select id="type">
  <option value="line">line</option>
  <option value="quadratic">quadratic</option>
  <option value="bezier" selected>bezier</option>
</select>
```

and some CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* ------------------------------------------------ */

HTML,BODY,OL,UL,LI,DL,DT,DD,P,DIV,SPAN {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------ */

BODY {
  margin:10px;
  background:#eee;
  color:#000;
}

#canvas {
  background:#fff;
}

.point {
  position:absolute;
  width:9px;height:9px;
  margin:-4px 0 0 -4px;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border:rgba(128, 128, 255, 0.8);
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  border-radius:4px;
}

.limiter{
  border:rgba(128, 1, 1, 0.8);
  background:rgba(255, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.line .cp1, .line .cp2
{
  display:none;
}

.quadratic .cp2{
  display:none;
}

.quadratic .cp1,
.bezier .cp1,
.bezier .cp2
{
  background:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  border:rgba(128, 255, 128, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: Damn, thats alot of code for a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you switch your creation of elements via innerHTML to something like

```
var el=document.createElement("DIV");
el.style.property="value";
el.addEventListener(myFunction, bubbleFlag);
POINTS.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: @Kabumbus: Don't use `setAttribute` on an HTML document, it's less easy-to-read than normal HTML DOM properties and there are bugs in it on IE. `div.id= ...`, `div.className= ...`. Running `String()` over the `id` here does nothing.

Comment: check if your /elementIdSring/ is really unique - that's what it needs to be. Why do you need the ID anyway?When you're binding to the created element (via eventListener), you always have the this-context within the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
POINTS.innerHTML +=
```

Don't ever do that.

This serialises the entire DOM contents of `POINTS` into an HTML string, adds a new string, and re-parses the concatenated string into new elements for everything in the `POINTS` element. As well as being slow, this loses all non-serialisable information from the previous content of the element, such as form field values, *event listeners* and JS references.

As in kstrieder's answer, use DOM operations.

Comment: So I see - will try as soon as possible - question is why I had clear html with 'innerHTML +='?